# Add Address fields in seller registration page of dokan plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I want to add address fields on seller registration page and also save this fields and updated in seller profile. I am using dokan wordpress plugin for multivendor. Please provide me suggestion and code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Seller can input his address in the seller welcome wizard that comes immediately after registration. But if you still need this in the registration-form you need to override this registration template inside your theme `/plugins/dokan/templates/global/seller-registration-form.php`

Add the address fields as set in this template :
`/plugins/dokan/templates/settings/address-form.php`

Then use `woocommerce_created_customer` hook to save your $POST data accordingly.

For saving address you can check this file as reference :
`/plugins/dokan/classes/template-settings.php line: 462`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p class="form-row form-group form-row-wide">
        <label for="dokan_address[city]"><?php _e( 'City', 'dokan-lite' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="city" id="dokan_address[city]" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $postdata['city'] ) ) echo esc_attr($postdata['dokan_address']); ?>" required="required" />
    </p>
```